# Is it possible to run fabric8 on vmplayer

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8, minikube

Is it possible to run fabric8 on vmplayer instead of virtualbox.?
whats it driver name.?

```
gofabric8 start --vm-driver=virtualbox // this one is for virtualbox

gofabric8 start --vm-driver=<vmplayer> // driver name for vmplayer
```

Answer (score 0):

No its not.

When using gofabric8 it installs using Minikube (or MiniShift if using OpenShift) and its really what they support. So go check out Minikube: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube and see what it support.